# Very basic Python to Excel how to

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to learn enough Python to write a program to extract data from multiple Excel files and compile them into one Excel file. I am hoping someone can help me with where to find a basic understanding of this. I know this is vague and all, but I am not really sure where to start just yet.

Comment: Do you really mean excel files? Or would CSV do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')

print book.nsheets
print book.sheet_names()

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols
```

You can also loop through each row of the excel document by sheet **name**:

```
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    print row
```

You can get the [xlrd module here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)
Or for a list of Python excel modules [here](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read and write CSV (comma separated values) files using Python 2.4 Distribution. Like most languages, file operations can be done with Python. Writing a CSV file with Python can be done by importing the CSV module and creating a write object that will be used with the WriteRow Method. Reading a CSV file can be done in a similar way by creating a reader object and by using the print method to read the file. As file operations require advanced concepts, some knowledge of programming with Python is required to read and write the CSV (comma separated values) files.

> Start by importing the CSV module:
>
> import csv
>
> We will define an object "writer" (named c), which can later be used
>   to write the CSV file.
>
> c = csv.writer(open("MYFILE.csv", "wb"))
>
> Now we will apply the method to write a row. Writerow The method takes
>   one argument - this argument must be a list and each list item is
>   equivalent to a column. Here, we try to make an address book:
>
> c.writerow(["Name","Address","Telephone","Fax","E-mail","Others"])

Comment: This text is just a copy-and-paste of a tutorial on the web.  Don't know who originated it, but [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2091-python-read-and-write-csv-files) is one location; you can tell from the Python 2.4 reference that it's pretty old.